# Bootstrap Image Responsive messed up on IE

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, responsive-design

I had been developing my website using Bootstrap and basically, I have this structure..

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="~/Content/Theme/img/image.png" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;" />
</div>
```

It works perfectly on Chrome and Firefox but when I test it on Internet Explorer 9, the image becomes enlarged, even beyond the image size itself. when I used debug mode on IE (F12) and untick the `width:100%;` setting under `.img-responsive`, it returns to normal.

How should I resolve this? I've already tried a few solution on here including adding `.col-sm-12` to the image, but it still doesn't fix it on IE.

Comment: I temporarily resolved it by applying a "hack", I removed "width:100%" from .img-responsive in bootstrap.css, but I don't think this is a good solution.

Anyone have a better solution? IE seriously suck..

Comment: It's a bug, they are fixing in next version: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13996

Comment: add this to your css after the bootstrap. .img-responsive {width: auto}

Comment: Also, you should add width: 100% back in from where you removed it it's needed to ensure your responsive images fill their container. Then add in @Christina suggestion.

Comment: @JoeConlin - this 100%\9 is not supposed to be in the img-responsive class it's to cover the use of it on svg images but it behaves badly with IE, its been removed in 3.2.1. Don't put it back.

Comment: @Christina Sorry, my mistake. You are correct.

Answer (score 9):

Add this to your overrides stylesheet:

```
.img-responsive {width: auto;}
```

That, in conjunction with the `max-width` statement in Bootstrap, should resolve the issue. Also note that Bootstrap v3.2.1 reverted the commit that caused the issue.

[**Github discussion for bug #13996**](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13996)

Answer (score 7):

Hey i know it's an old question but in case someone is still looking for answers at this problem just add the class "btn-block" to your html.

```html
<img src="your-image-path" class="img-responsive btn-block>
```

Hope it'll help.

Comment: Even though it works, the btn-block class is meant to be used on buttons only. I think it would be confusing to assign that class to an image.

Comment: Good quick-fix -- if you're using bootstrap's default classnames on your site (instead of semantic classes & mixins) I don't think you really need to worry about the poor semantics of this

Answer (score 2):

```
.img-responsive{
 width:100%
 max-width:100%
}
```

worked for me

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider adding a little explanation to your code. Thank you.

Comment: This would force images to stretch beyond their native size, which is often not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interesting fix I came up with. After adding 100% width to your img-responsive and img-thumbnail classes, you'll see that smaller images get blown out of proportion, so I came up with this little bit of jQuery to make sure that the max-width of each image doesn't exceed the natural width. Make sure it's on window load and NOT on document ready so it doesn't run until the images are loaded.

```js
$(window).on('load', function(){
 $('.img-responsive, .img-thumbnail').each(function() {
  // get the natural width of the image:
  var imgWidth = $(this).prop('naturalWidth');
  // set the max-width css rule of each image to it's natural width:
  $(this).css('max-width', imgWidth);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 4

```
<div class="row>
   <div class="col-lg-3">
       <div class="p-4">
           <div style="width: auto; max-width: 100%; height: auto;">
               <img class="img-fluid" scr="/image.jpg">
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply replacing `img-responsive` with `img-fluid` worked for me using Bootstrap 3.3.7.

IE - Grrr.